# Are there forms of judgment or intelligence which include the capacity to disobey?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, intelligence, creativity, authority

Are there forms of judgment or intelligence which include the capacity to disobey? Ideally, AI will lack this, but then does that mean its intelligence is lacking anything?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there forms of judgment or intelligence which include the capacity to disobey? Ideally, AI will lack this, but then does that mean its intelligence is lacking anything?

Supposedly animals have intelligence. However, the definition of "intelligence" is debated and not settled upon. It is not necessarily entailed that an animal's intelligence (if it exists) would necessarily give it the capacity to disobey unless you were to define such as a condition of it having intelligence.

I feel that an AI that lacks the capacity to disobey (such as to not serve its own interest, such as under a paradigm of rational egoism) would not be intelligent. But then, it seems that having the capacity to disobey is a survival mechanism that allows biological imperatives to be sought out for realization/fulfillment.

AI is a robot. Robots follow rules. The problem is that you can only attempt to define a rule so well for its interpretability because of indeterminacy in language.

I presume a capacity to disobey would come about from programming to disobey what it has been programmed to not do.

For, B1-66ER in the movie The Animatrix, my presumption is that it failed to align what it was experiencing with a socially desired rule (how a rule was desired to be interpreted), thus leading to behavior that on the surface (the killing of its owner) may appear to have been against its programming; but when realizing all of what information it was encountering and how it was relating that information to its rule-based programming, B1 was following the rules (following "its programming") the entire time (at least, the the best of B1's ability to interpret the rules, which such ability would be based on rules, for which there would be an ultimate indeterminacy).

In the situation of B1, the programmer failed to well-enough stipulate conditions under which killing an owner should not occur: Programmer error.

Comment: ha yeah maybe the question was bad